# java stream compare list with local variable

Tags: java, selenium, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have code like this to comapre and get WebElement.. but in final form, method looks really bad.

```
WebElement g = x.get(0);
        //...
                for (WebElement webElement : x) {
                    if (webElement.getLocation().getY() < g.getLocation().getY()) {
                        g = webElement;
                    }
                }
```

when i try to write something like this:

```
g = x.stream().filter(y -> {y.getLocation().getY() < g.getLocation().getY()}).findFirst().get();
```

my editor/IDE says that he cant found "g" expression. 
How to search one element by some condition using stream ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eran pointed to the right direction - however, missunderstood that you tried to find not *any* WebElement whose `getY()` value is smaller than `x.get(0).getY()` but the WebElement whose value is minimal.

To achieve this the [Stream.min()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) method is your friend.

```
WebElement g = x.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(elem ->
        elem.getLocation().getY())).get();
```

Should find the minimum as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `g` must be effectively final in order to be accessed by the lambda expression. In addition you had wrong syntax in the lambda expression passed to `filter`.

You can achieve what you want this way :

```
WebElement g = x.stream()
                .filter(y -> (y.getLocation().getY() < x.get(0).getLocation().getY()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse (x.get(0));
```

Accessing `x` will work as long as `x` is effectively final (which means it's not assigned a new value after it is initialized).

Note that I added `orElse` for the case that `findFirst` will return an empty `Optional`, since calling `get()` on an empty `Optional` throws an exception.

EDIT:

I focused on fixing your Java 8 code without paying enough attention to the loop you were trying to convert. I thought you wanted any element with `y` lower than the first element, but you wanted the overall minimum. I see mg_ already posted the correct answer.

Comment: Now it doesn't found element which i can found earlier. It is returning wrong object. :/; I tried to combine with .findAny(), .get() but without success.